# socket.io variable check

Tags: ajax, node.js, socket.io

Okay so basically I have a variable in ajax which I want to send to my socket.io server to check if the variable is already in a json array.

Ajax:

```
function isUniqueEmail(email) {
    //email checking script here
    $.get('info/mailcheck.js' + email, function(response) {
        if(response == 1) {
            alert("Your email is already on our list");
        }

        else {
            alert("We will add you shortly");
        };      
    })
};
```

the json array:

```
{"mail":
[
    "tom@gmail.com",
    "fred@gmail.com",
    "bob@gmail.com"
]}
```

The socket.io part is where im confused.  Basically it just needs to take the variable (an email) check if it is already in the array and return a 1 if it is or return a zero if not and write it in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about node.js but you could use a function a bit like the following to check if a value is in an array and push the value to it if it is not.

```
function pushToArray(value, array) {
    function inArray(val, arr) {
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == val) {
                 return true;
            } 
        return false;
    }
    if (inArray(value, array) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        array.push(value);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: it tried something like this but it doesn't write to the json file like i need it too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confused about how to get this to work with socket.io or just how to find the element in the array? If you're using node.js, just use the *array.**indexOf*** method:

```
//obj = {"mail": ["mail1@foo.com", "mail2@baz.com"]}
if (obj.mail.indexOf(email) != -1) {
  //We have your email!
}
else {
  //We don't
}
```

Comment: well basically i just gave part of the javascript there are other things in the javascript file like email validation ect.  But the part where it sends the variable to the socket.io script and the script accepts it is where i am confused.

Comment: Are you mixing traditional ajax calls with socket.io? That won't work. In order to use socket.io on the server, you need to connect to it from the client. See the examples at http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: oh so I would have to get the data strait from the input fields and not from ajax.  That said then i assume socket.io is able to write to json

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.Ajax is not the same as Socket.io - you should either be using one or the other, not both. Can you clarify your original question with exactly what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Okay let's go a different direction say I have 3 serverside files which preform different tasks do I need to start a http server in every file or just one and then they can do tasks when used

Comment: There should only be one server. You might want to do a bit more research about how web servers, ajax, sockets, etc. work - I think that would clarify a lot of your questions.